# Running balance with mySQL using UNION between tables

Tags: php, mysql

need some help with this, I have a table for the money in (payment received) and another table for the money out (expenses), here are a simplified format of the tables :

```
table : money_in
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   id  | invoiceID |   amount  |   Date     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   1   |   120     |    1200   | 10-08-2016 |
|   2   |   120     |    1000   | 09-08-2016 |
|   3   |   453     |    750    | 05-08-2016 |
|   4   |   111     |    400    | 02-08-2016 |
|   5   |   111     |    800    | 01-08-2016 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+

table : money_out
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   id  |purchaseID |   amount  |   Date     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   1   |   142     |    20     | 08-08-2016 |
|   2   |   142     |    50     | 07-08-2016 |
|   3   |   323     |    150    | 06-08-2016 |
|   4   |   344     |    100    | 04-08-2016 |
|   5   |   220     |    100    | 03-08-2016 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm creating a statement of account sheet, to display the running balance after each money in/out transaction. I used a query to record the UNION of bothe tables as follow :

```
$query = "SELECT p.*, i.invoiceID AS transactionID, i.invoiceNumber AS transactionName, i.clientID, i.type AS transactionType, c.id AS entityID, c.clientName FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . 'qi_payments' . " p , " . $wpdb->prefix . 'qi_invoices'. " i, " . $wpdb->prefix . 'qi_clients'. " c WHERE p.invoiceID = i.invoiceID AND i.clientID = c.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT pp.*, pur.purchaseID, pur.purchaseNumber, pur.supplierID, pur.type, s.id, s.supplierName FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . 'qi_purchases_payments' . " pp , " . $wpdb->prefix . 'qi_purchases'. " pur, " . $wpdb->prefix . 'qi_suppliers'. " s WHERE pp.purchaseID = pur.purchaseID AND pur.supplierID = s.id ORDER BY paymentDate DESC";
```

Now I have a table displayed properly but without the last column (Running balance), while it should look like this :

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+------ -----+
|   In  |    Out    |  Balance  |   Date     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------ -----+
| 1200  |           |  3730     | 10-08-2016 |
| 1000  |           |  2530     | 09-08-2016 |
|       |   20      |  1530     | 08-08-2016 |
|       |   50      |  1550     | 07-08-2016 |
|       |   150     |  1600     | 06-08-2016 |
|  750  |           |  1750     | 05-08-2016 |
|       |   100     |  1000     | 04-08-2016 |
|       |   100     |  1100     | 03-08-2016 |
|  400  |           |  1200     | 02-08-2016 |
|  800  |           |  800      | 01-08-2016 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm puzzled how to produce the Balance values, in SQL query or a PHP script.

Comment: @Strawberry order is by transaction date, descending

Comment: @Strawberry its a simplified version of the actual tables, but yes, basically every table have a transaction date. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@` variable, Like this:

```
select *
  from (
    select A.*,@sum:=@sum+zsum
      from (
            select *,amount as zsum from money_in
            union all
            select *,-amount from money_out
           ) A, (select @sum:=0) B
     order by id asc
  ) A
 order by id desc
```

Comment: i think it will work if the running balance start from 0, but in my case, the order is DESC by Date, the very first value of running balance in the records is the recent.

Comment: @LudwigArcache Notice I used to sort twise. The subquery use ascending order, from first transaction. In the outer query data re-sorted in reverse order

Comment: I just noticed how it is reversed, I will give it a try, and let you know. your solution seems functional.

Comment: Amazing, it works well. I did understand how it works. But what is A and B ? 2 temporary declared tables ?

Comment: @LudwigArcache A and B name alias for subquery. MySQL does not allow subqueries without names in FROM clause.

Comment: In my question, the running balance start from 0, most companies start from an Initial Capital. this value is stored in the options table.
Is it possible to include it ?

Comment: @LudwigArcache You can modify initial subquery B `(select @sum:=value from options ...) B`

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT date
     , money_in
     , money_out
     , @i:=@i + COALESCE(money_in,0) - COALESCE(money_out,0) balance
  FROM
     ( SELECT date
            , amount money_in
            , NULL money_out
         FROM money_in
        UNION
          ALL
       SELECT date
            , NULL
            , amount 
         FROM money_out
     ) x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY date;
```